# Ошибка переполнения стека

Tags: windows, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли ограничения по размеру на `char[]`? К примеру, у меня выделятся так

```
char[buf]= "";
```

где выше есть такое

```
#define buf 10000
```

но такого размера мало, увеличил его значительно - на 2 порядка и выдает такое сообщение:

> `Unhandled exception at 0x00ac81e7 in XXX.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.`

т.е. все равно переполняет? тока вот открывает какой-то левый файл при вылете, до этого указывал на строку в самой программе; эта ошибка вылетает, когда я пытаюсь сохранить данные расчетов в файл.

**Дополнено.**

При возврате к прежним размерам выдает следующую ошибку:

> Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in XXX.exe.

И указывает на строку вида: `strcat_s(cResult,";");` где `char cResult[BUF_SIZE]="";`

Comment: Извиняюсь за назойливость, но как сделать чтобы дописывать в такую переменную? К примеру, я записал туда уже что-то вот так: 
`memcpy(strToAdd, &Temp, sizeof(Temp));` теперь надо дописать туда же Temp, который получу вот так 
`sprintf_s(Temp,"%.2f",myBaseData.GetMod(i-1));`

Comment: Копируете указатель buf в buf2 (чтобы не потерять его), затем двигаете указатель buf2 += sizeof(Temp), и опять делаете memcpy(buf2, Temp, <здесь сколько хотите копировать символов>).

Comment: Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код и заодно напишите, как объявлены переменные и структуры. А то похоже, что в первом цикле

for(int j=0; j < temp; j++) {...} 

Вы сравниваете целое с указателем на строку.

Comment: Не как его не отформатировать почему то само окно с комментарием не крутится дальше чем на пару строк(( сразу же возвращается в начало...

Comment: Ну, сделайте в окне ответа (4 пробела в начале строки и не жалейте ньюлайнов). Когда будете набирать в окошке снизу виден форматированный результат. Только пропишите, что это продолжение вопроса, а не ответ.

Comment: Стыдно не знать как работает стек, как он расширяется и что такое сторожевые страницы.

Comment: Ответ не по существу :-(

Comment: _chkstk

Comment: Вот и пытаюсь понять...((

Answer (score 2):

Существует ограничение на размер стека. В твоем случае я бы рекомендовал выделять память не статически, а динамически, ограничение все-равно будет(но очень большое, если мне память не изменяет 2 ГБ на 32-битных, и 4 ГБ на 64-битных ОС), но скорее всего для твоих нужд хватит. Динамически это вот так:

```
char * buf = new char[10000000];
...
delete[] buf;
```

Comment: Тут buf имеется ввиду сама переменная, в которую будем записывать?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: В таком случае, мне нужно по символьно в неё заисывать? К примеру, у меня есть char[100] размером в 100 элементов и каждый элемент отдельно записывать в цикле? Или есть какая-то функция, чтобы char[xxx] записать в него сразу?

Comment: Если задаче не хватает размера стека, значит надо пересмотреть алгоритм ее решения. 

А если серьезно, мне кажется, что у Вас strcat() в бесконечном цикле, где-то условие выхода не проверяется.

Comment: Конечно, есть, например, memcpy(...), strncpy(...). Вот так в вашем случае будет выглядеть (пусть есть переменная char tmp[100]) memcpy(buf, &tmp, 100), а strncpy(buf, &tmp, 100);

Comment: Но при небольшом интервале все работает же....когда задаю интервал в тысячу и более то такая ошибка... в эту переменную записываются все результаты расчетов

Comment: Ну, не влезли вы в стек, - значит надо переходить на динамическую память, ну или как сказал @avp искать косяки в алгоритме.